# itextsharp 5.0 digital signature not correct. Document was corrupted after signing

Tags: c#, itext

I add to pdf document X509certificate and visible signature element using iTextSharp. The code does not cause errors, but while i open signed document, appears message that the certificate is invalid because document was corrupted after signing. I added the certificate to the trusted list. What could be the problem?
The code I used here

```
public void Sign()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetSert();
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate) };

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\ Test.pdf");
        PdfDictionary dict = reader.GetPageN(reader.NumberOfPages);
        IList<iTextSharp.text.Image> list = GetImagesFromPdfDict(dict, reader);
        PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new
        FileStream(NewFP, FileMode.Create), '\0', null, true);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(reader.NumberOfPages);
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.SignatureAppearance;
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle signPosition = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(cropBox.GetLeft(reader.NumberOfPages) + 55, Y, cropBox.GetLeft(reader.NumberOfPages) + 260, Y - 80); 

        byte[] pk = certificate.GetRawCertData();

        sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        sap.Acro6Layers = true;
        sap.Layer4Text = "";
        sap.Layer2Text = "";
        sap.SignatureGraphic = list[0];
        sap.Render =
        PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.Graphic;
        PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADBE_X509_RSA_SHA1,
        PdfName.ADBE_X509_RSA_SHA1);
        dic.Cert = certificate.GetRawCertData();
        dic.Date = new PdfDate(sap.SignDate);
        dic.Name = PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields(chain[0]).GetField("CN");
        sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
        int csize = pk.Length;
        Dictionary<PdfName, int> ex = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>(1);
        ex.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, csize * 2 + 2);
        exc[PdfName.CONTENTS] = csize * 2 + 2;
        sap.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS;

        sap.SetVisibleSignature(signPosition, reader.NumberOfPages, null);
        sap.SetCrypto(null, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
        sap.PreClose(ex);
         byte[] outc = new byte[csize]; 
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();

        Array.Copy(pk, 0, outc, 0, pk.Length);

        dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new
        PdfString(outc).SetHexWriting(true));

        sap.Close(dic2);

    }
```

[image: Signature error]

And my signed document [here](https://gofile.io/d/fKJlZv)

30.11.2020
I try to enctypted current range stream using next code

```
 sap.PreClose(ex);

        Stream s = sap.GetRangeStream();
        MemoryStream ss = new MemoryStream();
        int read = 0;
        int len = (int)s.Length+1;
        byte[] buff = new byte[len];
        MessageBox.Show(s.Length.ToString());
        
        while ((read = s.Read(buff, 0, len)) > 0)
        {
            ss.Write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        byte[] ToS = ss.ToArray();
        ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(ToS);
        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(
            SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier,
            certificate);
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        byte[] signedbytes = signedCms.Encode();

        // Set signature to document
        byte[] outc = new byte[signedbytes.Length];
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        Array.Copy(signedbytes, 0, outc, 0, signedbytes.Length);
        dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(outc).SetHexWriting(true));
        sap.Close(dic2);
```

but it works worse than the previous one. I got error:
[image: New error]

Maybe signing incorrectly? My certificate alghoritm is sha256RSA

//09.12.2020
I achieved success using the following code:

```
 public void PrepareSignatureAndGetHash(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {

        using (var reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Test.pdf"))
        {
            using (var fileStream = new
                    FileStream(@"C:\Output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fileStream, '0', null, true))
                {
                    var signatureAppearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                    Rectangle cropBox = reader.GetCropBox(reader.NumberOfPages);
                    Rectangle signPosition = new Rectangle(cropBox.GetRight(0) - 20, cropBox.GetBottom(0), cropBox.GetRight(0) - 250, cropBox.GetBottom(0) + 80);
                    signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(signPosition, reader.NumberOfPages, null);
                    signatureAppearance.Reason = "Sig";
                    signatureAppearance.Layer2Text = "";
                    signatureAppearance.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"C:\Stamp.png");


                    if (!cert.HasPrivateKey) { MessageBox.Show("Не найдено закрытого ключа"); }
                    var keyPair = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert.PrivateKey).Private;
                    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcCert = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(cert);
                    var chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> { bcCert };
                    IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(keyPair, "SHA-256");

                    MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Using a low level code I couldn't sign correctly

Comment: How are you validating the certificate, on what machine, and with what user?  The certificate need to be loaded into both the user and machine stores.  To verify the certificate a virtual connection is made.  So as part of the connection a TLS authentication is performed.  You could be using TLS 1.0/1.1 which Microsoft disabled in June as part of a security push.  So you have to make sure TLS 1.2/1.3 is used.  The operating System also has to support TLS 1.2/1.3.  Itext 5.0 doesn't support TLS 1.2 or higher.  Upgrade to Itext 5.5 : https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases/tag/5.5.13.2

Comment: Please share an example pdf signed by your code for analysis.

Comment: I attached test pdf file to my post. If i signed that document manually the signature is valid. The certification path can be traced in both cases. The problem is that the document is corrupted after signing using itext

Comment: Ok, having looked at your example file I have an idea what to look for in your code. There are numerous issues. **First of all, you don't sign at all**, instead of a signature value you inject the certificate: `pk` should be the signature value of the range stream but it is `certificate.GetRawCertData()`. Thus, after `sap.PreClose` retrieve the range stream from `sap` and sign its contents. Furthermore, you chose a signing scheme that is only supported in a limited degree, **adbe.x509.rsa_sha1**. Preferable are **adbe.pkcs7.detached** and **ETSI.CAdES.detached**.

Comment: Also you use the old, very low-level signing API. You should update to at least a higher 5.3.x, better to 5.5.x., and use the newer signing API.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. And how i can sign stream contents? Now i got `sap.RangeStream` and convert it to byte array, then i put it to PDFDictionary and closed PdfSignatureAppearance, but i again get the same error in document. 
I using adbe.x509.rsa_sha1 because, when im used adbe.pkcs7.detached, i cant view the certificate information in pdf file. Sorry for my english

Comment: *"And how i can sign stream contents?"* - That depends on how you can use your private key. You have a `X509Certificate2`. Sometimes a private key is coupled with it. In that case you can use it for signing. How exactly depends on the nature of your key. is it RSA? DSA? ECDSA? Something else?

Comment: My certificate have a sha256RSA algoritm. I've made some progress in getting errors (i extend my post)

Comment: Concerning your edit: the byte ranges in question are finalized before `sap.PreClose(ex)`. As your posted change starts there, that change is not related to the Adobe error message.

Comment: One error I see: in `byte[] outc` you create an array as long as `signedbytes`. This is wrong, it must be as large as the reserved **Contents** space, i.e. `csize`. You did that better in the original code. You have to consider, though, that you should determine `csize` differently.

Comment: Concerning your December 9th update - if you can use that high level API, you should use it. Merely that requires an update from the version 5.0 you mention in the question title.

Comment: The problem is that some of our extensions use iText 5.0 and there is a version conflict when registering 5.5. It looks like the only way to connect 5.5 right now is through dynamic loading reflection

Comment: There is no option of updating the code which uses iText 5.0 and upgrading to iText 5.5 globally? iText 5.0 is ancient, and there were very many improvements in the versions leading to 5.5...

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment I don't have access to the source code of the module that uses 5.0. Using dynamic loading 5.5 allows me to solve the problem